# How to loop through the columns in an R data frame and create a new data frame using the column name in each iteration?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have an R data frame dftotal

```
i  A  B C  D
1  4 15 4 12
2 13  4 4  7 
3  1  1 3  8 
4  3 11 1  9
```

I want to write a loop that goes through the columns (A,B,C,D) and creates a new data frame each time, so that I have a data frame for each column:

dfA:

```
i  A  
1  4 
2 13  
3  1   
4  3
```

And dfB:

```
i  B 
1 15 
2  4 
3  1  
4 11
```

Etc...

I tried:

```
List <- colnames(dftotal)
List <- List[-1]
for (j in length(List)) 
    {
      df <- data.frame(dftotal$i,dftotal[List[j]]) 
      assign(paste("df",List[j]), df)

    }
```

But that returned a data frame only for the last column in my list. It seems to have overwritten the other data frames that were created in the loop.

```
df <- data.frame(dftotal$i,dftotal[List[1]]) 
      assign(paste("df",List[1]), df)
```

Works fine, when I run it column by column manually.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `lapply(df[-1], function(i)cbind(df$i, i))`

Comment: or `lapply(sapply(iris, function(x) data.frame(x)), cbind)`

Comment: @Sotos inside or outside the loop?

Comment: Do not assign separate data.frames into the global environment. Keep them together in a list like the previous comments show.

Comment: Nowhere in the loop. On its own

Comment: Or something like : `lapply(seq_along(df), function(x) df[x])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record - replying to the question of what you are doing wrong:

`for (j in length(List))`

should rather be

`for (j in 1:length(List))`

Comment: Thanks. I also understand now why its a bad idea :-(

Answer (score 0):

> Assume these below are vectors

```
i <- c(1,2,3,4)
A <- c(4,13,1,3)
B <- c(15,4,1,11)
C <- c(4,4,3,1)
D <- c(12,7,8,9)
```

> Data frame for all i, A, B, C, D

```
MM <- cbind(i,A,B,C,D)
MM <- data.frame(MM)

List <- colnames(MM)
List <- List [-1]
```

> The function to create specific data frames df1, df2, df3 and df4

```
for (j in 1:length(List)) {
```

`df <- data.frame(MM$i,MM[,List[j]])`
  `colnames(df) <- c("i", paste("df",List[j], sep = ""))`
  `assign(paste("df",j, sep = ""),df)`
`}`