# how to create subsets of data. frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two data frames one with 94 rows and 167 columns (`df_1`) and the other one with 94 rows and 1 column (`df_2`) and I would like to do 167 different data frames with each column of the first data frame and the same column of the second data frame, I have tried with a for loop like the next

```
for (i in seq_len(ncol(df_1))){
    df_[[i]] <- data.frame(df_1[sort(rownames(df_1)),i,df_2[sort(rownames(df_2)),])
}
```

But it does not work, can someone help me?

Comment: Please include a [minimal & reproducible code example including sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think to join two df if they have similar column name use the below code

```
library(gtools)
df3<- smartbind(df1,df2)  ####df1 with 167 column and df2 with 1 column
```

this will give you a single data frame and to create various data frames use the answer used. in the below thread:

[How to loop through the columns in an R data frame and create a new data frame using the column name in each iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202419/how-to-loop-through-the-columns-in-an-r-data-frame-and-create-a-new-data-frame-u)